How many galaxies does the Pisces–Cetus Supercluster Complex contain?
I have been reading about galaxy groups, clusters, superclusters, galaxy filaments, and which our galaxy belongs to. Afterward, I read estimations about how many galaxies these structures contain from our Local Group, up to the Laniakea Supercluster, which is expected to contain approximately 100,000 galaxies.
However, I haven't been able to ascertain how many its parent structure, the Pisces–Cetus Supercluster Complex (which our Laniakea Supercluster belongs to), contains. Does an estimation exist for how many galaxies the Pisces–Cetus Supercluster Complex contains? If so, how many?

I can't seen a number (which is probably not well constrained)  WP mentions that the Virgo super cluster has 0.1% of the mass, so if the Virgo Supercluster has about 4000-5000 galaxies, then this complex would have about 4000000  OTOH it notes five main components, and if they are all about equal then the about 500000 galaxies. I'm sure the error bars are quite large!

The answer depends on how small you want to go in terms of what counts as a galaxy. For example, the Local Group has three (non-dwarf) galaxies... or four, if you count galaxies with at least $10^{9}$ solar masses in stars, or several dozen if you go lower (there are more small galaxies than big galaxies).
